# Posted model properties from kendo grid is null in controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I find that the posted model from kendo grid is null in the controller action. There are a lot of related forums here but nothing I could use as a solution to my issue.

This code in cshtml is as below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Skills)
.Name("skillGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Bound(p => p.SkillNameNew).ClientTemplate("#= SkillNameNew #" +
"<input type='hidden' name='Skills[#= index(data)#].SkillNameNew' value='#= SkillNameNew#' />")
.Title("Skill Name");

columns.Bound(p => p.SkillName).Hidden().ClientTemplate("#= SkillName #" +
"<input type='hidden' name='Skills[#= index(data)#].SkillName' value='#= SkillName #' />");

columns.Template(p => p.Proficiency).ClientTemplate("<div id='star' data-text='#: SkillName #' data-score='#: Proficiency #' role='rating' ></div>" +"<input type='hidden' id='prof' name='Skills[#= index(data)#].Proficiency' value='#= Proficiency #' />").Title("Proficiency");

columns.Bound(p => p.YearsOfExp).ClientTemplate("#= (YearsOfExp == null || YearsOfExp == ' ' || YearsOfExp == '') ? '' : kendo.parseInt(YearsOfExp) #" + "<input type='hidden' name='Skills[#= index(data)#].YearsOfExp' value='#= YearsOfExp #' />").Title("Years Of Exp");

columns.Bound(p => p.LastUsedYear).ClientTemplate("#= (LastUsedYear == null || LastUsedYear == '0' || LastUsedYear == '') ? '' : kendo.parseInt(LastUsedYear) #" +"<input type='hidden' name='Skills[#= index(data)#].LastUsedYear' value='#=LastUsedYear#' />").Title("Last Used Year");

columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(40);})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Events(events => events.DataBound("DataBound"))
.Resizable(re => re.Columns(true))
.Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(false))
.Sortable()
.Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Virtual(true))
.Groupable()
.Filterable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:100%;" })
.DataSource(d => d.Ajax()
                   .Batch(true)
                   .ServerOperation(false)
                   .PageSize(Constants.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)
                   .Model(model => model.Id(l => l.SkillName))
```

The controller action has the below signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateExperience(EditCandidateExperienceViewModel model)
{
------
}
```

Skills is a property of type "List" in "EditCandidateExperienceViewModel"

It looks like the model property names and the names bound in the grid are consistent. Please let me know what I could be missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated as I have run out of ideas on this.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

If `Skills` is `List<T>`, then decorate your action like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateExperience(T model)
{
  ------
}
```

You are giving grid the  different model and forcing to post the parent model `EditCandidateExperienceViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks Bishnu, the skills grid is in a tab/page that accepts "EditCandidateExperienceViewModel" along with other controls. The skills grid is bound to a property "List<SkillListViewItemViewModel>" in "EditCandidateExperienceViewModel". I tried your suggestion as well and passed in the "List<SkillListViewItemViewModel>" but it got passed as null.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass list of model from the grid. for that you have to pass `IEnumerable` or `IList` type of list to the controller.

Comment: Thanks Anand, this did not work, i am not sure if i am doing anything wrong with the names here, the binding may not be right. The skills does get populated but when posting back loses values.